# Hive classpath not being found from ODBC

Tags: java, hadoop, odbc, hive

I'm using a custom jar file to process Omniture logs via Hive  ( com.tgam.hadoop.mapred.OmnitureDataFileInputFormat )

Originally, I went through a process of adding it as a jar manually whenever I needed to process impacted tables:

```
ADD JAR C:\hdp\jars\OmnitureDataFileInputFormat.jar;
```

Now I'm using the hive-site.xml file to set this

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
    <value>file:///C:/hdp/jars/OmnitureDataFileInputFormat.jar</value>
    <description />
  </property>
```

and so now I can access the relevant Hive tables without running the ADD JAR command from the command line tool

However, when I try to run the exact same query via Excel ODBC, it fails with this error in hive.log

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tgam.hadoop.mapred.OmnitureDataFileInputFormat
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getInputFormatClass(Table.java:300)
```

any ideas where I need to put the jar to be able  to access this data directly without  having to create temporary staging tables

thanks

Answer (score 0):

what an idiot, I realised the/a answer about 2 seconds after pressing "send" - I copied the jar to hive-0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041\lib and restarted

might  not be recommended, but it worked ...